# Auth0 integration in Flutter: Android not returning to app after login/logout

Tags: android, flutter, auth0

I am trying to integrate Auth0 authentication into my Flutter app using the flutter_auth0 package. I followed the Quickstart guide provided by Auth0, and the authentication flow works correctly on iOS. However, on Android, the app does not return to the application after login/logout.

```
    defaultConfig {
       
        applicationId "club.********.***"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        manifestPlaceholders += [auth0Domain: "**********-dev.us.auth0.com", auth0Scheme: "https"]
    }
```

and here is the callback url I set in auth0 dashboard

`https://*********-dev.us.auth0.com/android/club.*******.***/callback`

the app works fine on iOS but in android it is showing not found in chrome window, I tried replacing the scheme but then its not even letting me authorise

here is the stack trace

```
V/CallbackHelper(17191): The Callback URI is: https://*********-dev.us.auth0.com/android/club.********.*****/callback
V/OAuthManager(17191): Using PKCE authentication flow
D/OAuthManager(17191): Using the following Authorize URI: https://*********-dev.us.auth0.com/authorize?scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&response_type=code&code_challenge=bkq4fwCfo94X8fvXcwtJ7OVRuuVrwUpkwtccE6CzlNw&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAtZmx1dHRlciIsImVudiI6eyJhbmRyb2lkIjoiMzMifSwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMS4wIn0%3D&client_id=*************&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F*******************.us.auth0.com%2Fandroid%2Fclub.***********.*****%2Fcallback&state=G9qnj7Be7MAqEEWoT-X9DISYSm7LQ-Lg70vggLGdeys&nonce=ABj2J1Muay7k0stakvwMee-C9rXMylTC8eFgC82VJeU
D/TWAProviderPicker(17191): Found TWA provider, finishing search: com.android.chrome
V/CustomTabsController(17191): Trying to bind the service
V/CustomTabsController(17191): Bind request result (com.android.chrome): true
V/CustomTabsController(17191): Trying to bind the service
V/CustomTabsController(17191): Bind request result (com.android.chrome): true
D/CustomTabsController(17191): CustomTabs Service connected
D/CustomTabsController(17191): Launching URI. Custom Tabs available: true
W/Parcel  (17191): Expecting binder but got null!
```

the call back url in chrome when copy pasted is the exact same url which I gave in auth0.

can anyone help me?

Comment: your using `https` as your `auth0scheme` which means you plan to use `Android app links`. Is that correct? If not, then can you try changing to a `custom scheme name` ?

Comment: I tried using a custom scheme name in the build.gradle but then , still it's redirecting to the https one and callback url mismatch is shown.  the auth0 documentation suggest an https one